# Facebook deauthorize callback C#

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've started a simple facebook iframe application. I created a handler to deal with the deauthorize callback (ashx) with the following code:

```
    FacebookSignedRequest signedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(appSecret,context.Request.Form["signed_request"]);
    //flag signedRequest.UserId as inactive;
```

Why isn't Facebook calling my callback that I specified in the app settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook will call that callback when a user has removed your application from his list of apps at http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications.  Are you sure your URL is publicly accessible?  Are you sure you don't need any cookies to access the callback?